# Revellers in BBC News

Tags: word-meaning

[image]

In this article, what does the subtitle mean?

I mean "Revellers must ~the art trail."

I know the literal meaning but I guess that doesn't  enough to get the whole meaning.

Does "Revler" have the other meaning?
Or is there anything  else ambitious?

Please hepl me to get the proper idea of it.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: It's a facetious usage as cited. *Revelers* normally means *partygoers* (people out partying / having a good time). Your promotional material implies that following their "art trail" is ***fun*** (like going to a party). Requiring customers to swear they're "up to no good" (doing things they shouldn't) adds the further implication that traipsing round the trail will be ["naughty but nice".](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/naughty+but+nice)

Comment: Personally, I think using 'revellers' there is inappropriate. You usually see the word used in news stories about parties, e.g.  Christmas, New Year, stag, birthday, etc,  especially the ones where alcoholic drinks are consumed. It's not in the art trail promotional material; it's the BBC News website caption for the photo of the promotional material. I would have used something like "participants".

Answer (score 1):

This is a reference to the Harry Potter books. In the books, there is a magical map that will only appear if you say the passphrase "I solemnly swear I am up to no good." The article is linking the street art map the revellers will have to follow with the map from the books - it's just meant as a humorous reference rather than literal fact. (https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Marauder%27s_Map)